# Mysqli selecting youtube watch id from db, inserting into php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, youtube, embed

I've been wrestling with this for several hours now. Searched google and stackoverflow. Not getting anywhere. I'm trying to access a youtube watch id from a database, and insert it into an embed. No errors. $con is fine. Accessing the table is fine. My sql query works in phpmyadmin. The embed video shows, but doesn't have a watch idea, so it just gives fuzz when you press play. I'm out of ideas. Please help, and thank you very much.

Here is my php.

```
$sqlVideo = "SELECT watchid FROM video WHERE id = 1;";

if ($resultVideo = mysqli_query($con, $sqlVideo))
{
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultVideo)) 
      {

echo '<embed width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$row['watchid'].'?        autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></embed>';
}
}
```

Comment: Looks fine, What's the output?

Comment: Pretty sure it's http://www.youtube.com/embed/

Comment: `var_dump($row)` after the 2nd {. What's the output?

Comment: Ah, I think I'm getting. //www.youtube.com/embed/ XWIvfE01J0k ?autoplay=1. What's the fix?

Comment: ://www.youtube.com/embed/XWIvfE01J0k?autoplay=1 works for me - sure the space is meant to be there?

Comment: I'm getting a space. ...embed/ XWIvfE01J0k ?autoplay... I can't figure out why I'm getting it, or why there's a space. Also, why did you use a :?

Comment: It must be in the row. Try `trim($row['watchid'])`.

Comment: You nailed it. God, I don't know how long it would have taken me to notice that on my own. Thank you! I'll try to keep a closer eye on my outputs.